# RestAssured JsonPath to String

Tags: java, json, string, rest-assured

Is there a way to convert the whole JSON path data to a string in Java?

I am working on APIs and their responses are in JSON format. It is easy to understand the JSON structure through Postman/WireShark but I am trying to run an API request through Java, grab the response, convert the raw response to JSON, convert JSON response to a string format and print it. The method '.getString()' is to access a particular element and not the whole data. The method '.toString()' does not work on JSON data either.

```
    JsonPath json = (ConvertRawFiles.rawtoJSON(response));
    String id   = json.get("id");
    log.info("The id is " + id);

    JsonPath json = (ConvertRawFiles.rawtoJSON(response));
    String complete_json_data   = ???;
    log.info("The complete json data is " + complete_json_data);
```

The code snippet which is mentioned "???" is what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   json.toString();   is this the way you are doing?

Comment: @Kalyan Satya , your friend Google would have instantly given you myriad results. Anyways, I have posted answer. HTH.

Comment: Please specifically mention what language you are asking about

Comment: @Kalyan Satya ,  as a deed of appreciation it is always nice to accept or upvote an answer which suits you best (if at all any answer satisfies your need). .

Comment: Thank you for your time Vineet but I am still figuring out ways to address the raised concern.

Comment: Any error raised?

Comment: The data I am concerned about changing to String belongs to JsonPath class. And the answers provided here are addressing Json Objects. I think there is a difference which has not been observed by me. Coming back to the question, the conversion to String is still not happening.

Comment: I found the method I have been looking for and have answered the question. Thank you for your suggestions everyone.

Comment: You should mention where you get this `JsonPath` class from

Comment: @BhartiMohane I have tried to do it that way but found that '.prettify()' method does what I wanted to do.

Comment: @cricket_007 JsonPath is from the 'io.restassured'' package and I think it is obvious. Isn't it?

Comment: No, it isn't. For example https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: @cricket_007 Understood. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The methods which can convert a JsonPath object into a String are:

```
JsonPath json = (ConvertRawFiles.rawtoJSON(response));
String complete_json_data = json.prettify();
```

and

```
JsonPath json = (ConvertRawFiles.rawtoJSON(response));
String complete_json_data = json.prettyPrint();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { "field1":"foo", "age":55, "city":"Honolulu"};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```